# Using MTCNN with a webcam via OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, neural-network, face, facial-identification

I wish to be able to use a webcam and utilize MTCNN as the primary facial detector. Just as one can use Haar Cascades, I want to use MTCNN to find faces on my webcam

This video is about breaking MTCNN, but nonetheless provides insight into my goal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OY70OIS8bxs

Here is my code so far. It used to be so that the plot would show and I'd have to "X" it out but now it just doesn't work

```
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN 
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

cap =  cv.VideoCapture(0)

detector = MTCNN()

#face = detector.detect_faces(img)


while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if (ret):
        # Our operations on the frame come here
        gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        ax = pyplot.gca()
        face = detector.detect_faces(frame)
        face = pyplot.imread(frame)
        x, y, width, height = face[0]['box']
        rect = Rectangle((x, y), width, height, fill=False, color='red')
        ax.add_patch(rect)
        pyplot.imshow(frame)
        cv.imshow('frame',gray)
        pyplot.show()
     # Display the resulting frame
        #cv.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I was hoping someone could help me...

Answer (score 2):

Im experiencing a similiar issue at the moment. I have a program which crops the face of a video. Im using OpenCV to read in the frames and then perform the cropping on them. After that I want to save the cropped face video to a new video.

First I was also using Haar Cascade. Everything is working fine but has some general performance lacks --> It often doesnt recognize faces.

Now I wanted to use MTCNN. I changed the code in order to work with MTCNN. Everything is working fine --> It reads in the frames, performs the crop on it etc. HOWEVER, as soon as I go to saving the video the trouble happens. The code runs fine, however after opening the saved video I get an error that the video is corrupted.

I was sitting for 2h and was so confused, because the code is identical. All the outputs are same (i.e. format, size etc)

I now have to conclude that there is some error between MTCNN and Opencv. Even though this totally doesnt make sense to me why this should happen.

Update:
If you run the following code: It runs fine and the video is saved again. However if you uncomment the 2 lines at the top --> it will corrupt the file and you will no longer get a working video back. Unfortunately, I could not figure out the reason for that yet.

```
import cv2

# from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
# cropper = MTCNN()

read_video = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
fps = read_video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
write_video = cv2.VideoWriter('new3.mp4', fourcc, fps, (256,256))
images = []

success,image = read_video.read()
count = 0
while success:
    print(count)
    images.append(image)
    success, image = read_video.read()
    count += 1

for i in images:
    write_video.write(cv2.resize(i, (256, 256), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA))
```

Comment: If you already figure it out, Don't forget to update your answer. We're curious too.

Comment: have a look at the update --> no solution, just a proof that MTCNN is the origin for that

Comment: well... we're gonna rely to clarifai for now.

Answer (score 1):

This is my code to use MTCNN on a webcam and it works

```
import cv2
from mtcnn import MTCNN

ksize = (101, 101)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX


def find_face_MTCNN(color, result_list):
    for result in result_list:
        x, y, w, h = result['box']
        roi = color[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        cv2.rectangle(color,
                      (x, y), (x+w, y+h),
                      (0, 155, 255),
                      5)
        detectedFace = cv2.GaussianBlur(roi, ksize, 0)
        color[y:y+h, x:x+w] = detectedFace
    return color


video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
detector = MTCNN()

while True:
    _, color = video_capture.read()
    faces = detector.detect_faces(color)
    detectFaceMTCNN = find_face_MTCNN(color, faces)
    cv2.imshow('Video', detectFaceMTCNN)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

About the problem below:

change

`fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')`

to

`fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')`

It worked for [me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803078/how-to-write-on-video-with-cv2-and-mtcnn-im-facing-problems-with-fourcc/64855863#64855863)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code:

```
import cv2 
from mtcnn import MTCNN

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
detector = MTCNN()


while True:

ret,frame = cap.read()

output = detector.detect_faces(frame)

for single_output in output:
    x,y,w,h = single_output['box']
    cv2.rectangle(frame,pt1=(x,y), pt2=(x+w,y+h),color=(255,0,0),thickness=2)
cv2.imshow('win',frame)

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ('x'):
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Dependencies**, install these using the command in terminal then run the code above.

- `pip install mtcnn`
- `pip install opencv-python`

This works for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).